# Why Mayumi wears a sailor uniform, different than the other girls, if they are in the same class for such a long time?

Tags: joshi-kausei

She in not a transfer student, and while she is not Momoko's classmate for as long as Shibumi, it is safe to assume she is of the same age and is in the same class for a long time.

Why she is still using a junior uniform?